# android studio button sometimes doesn't work

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I have a menu activity from which I want to go to the meat of my application. When I press the button to do so, it sometimes opens the main screen within a few moments, sometimes takes longer, and in many cases, doesn't work at all. In the case that it doesn't work, the button will usually work after clicking it again. I have used debug statements to determine that the button is (sometimes) not registering the clicks at all. What could be causing this?

Comment: nobody can help you if you don't provide code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem sometimes, this happens with me because my crappy mouse, and sometimes it is caused by the emulator which starts lagging with time and not recording my clicks properly, from time to time I just to wipe the data of the emulator to make work properly again.
One good solution to check if your doing things right, is to install your app in a real device and check if the button is working properly.